# How to return results in random order with Mongoose (working with skip, limit)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have some bookschema, and I want to get books in a random order whenever the page loads. I cannot shuffle the find result like this:

```
        const books = await BookModel.find({}, (err, res) => { // eslint-disable-line
            // console.log(res);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }).limit(args.limit || 3).skip(args.offset || 3).lean();

        return _.shuffle(books);
```

Reason being that on each additional skip/limit, e. g. when the user scrolls down to load more results, the randomization would start again from scratch and the frontend results would shuffle around.

What I want is that it loads the first e. g. 9 results in randomized order, then loads another 9 in randomized order. Is there any way to do this with Mongoose out of the box?

Comment: just curious if you have a solution for this. would be nice posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can solve this the following way:

=> we need to send the already read ids to the server for the next chunk

```
...
let ids = [];   
if (retrievedIds.length) {
      ids = retrievedIds.map((id) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
    }

let filter = { _id: { $nin: ids} }

db.users.aggregate([
   { $match: filter }, //
   { $sample: { size: 10 } }
])
```